# Проксирование запросов в golang с помощью nginx

Tags: nginx, golang, proxy, config

Я собираюсь использовать прокси для своих запросов. В коде я это делаю так:

```
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(ProxyServerUrl) // proxyUrl - "http://nginxHost:nginxPort" 
if err != nil {...}
client.Transport = &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}
resp, err := client.Get(requestUrl) // requestUrl - "https://domain/..."
...
```

Мне нужно как-то поднять и настроить nginx чтобы я мог его использовать в своем коде, как proxyUrl. По большей части меня интересует содержание `nginx.conf` для этого кейса.

Comment: Очень странное желание. Nginx это не proxy-сервер.

Comment: Я могу как-то использовать его в качестве прокси сервера?

Comment: @AlexanderTsapkov в nginx есть proxy_pass. нужные запросы перенаправляете куда хотите через него.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor разобрался, снова спасибо Вам, большое. Добавите ответ, чтобы я мог отметить его, как правильный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в конфиге nginx можно перенаправлять входящие запросы на другой сервер через proxy_pass.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ru.stackoverflow.com;
    ...

location /match/here {
    proxy_pass http://example.com;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.XX.YY;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for
}

}
```

В примере `/match/here` в конце описания сервера не указан URI адрес. При получении запроса, соответствующего этой настройке, он будет без изменения передан вышестоящему серверу. Например, при обращении к /match/here/please, URI будет отправлен по адресу http://example.com/match/here/please.

Во втором примере заголовок `host` соответствующего запроса будет изменен на значение переменной `$host`, которое должно содержать изначально запрошенный хост. Заголовок `X-Forwarded-Proto` дает вышестоящему серверу знать о том, какая схема была использована при изначальном запросе (http/https).
`X-Real-IP` имеет значение IP адреса клиента. Заголовок `X-Forwarded-For` содержит список прокси серверов, по которым прошел запрос до настоящего момента. В данном примере мы присваиваем ему значение переменной `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for`. Она содержит в себе полученный заголовок `X-Forwarder-For` плюс добавляет свой сервер в этот список.

подробнее [тут](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html)

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо!